# getClientOriginalName() error while trying to upload image gallery

Tags: php, image, laravel, gallery

I'm currently learning laravel and I'm stuck at uploading image gallery & header image to a specific folder. This is my controller code: (I'm uploading images on "edit" page)

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

    $findObject = Accommodation::find($id);
    $findObject->update($request->all());

    Gallery::destroy('objects_id', $id);
    foreach ($request['img'] as $img) {
        $gallery = new Gallery();
        $gallery->objects_id=$id;
        $gallery->img=$img;
        $gallery->save();


        $file[0] = $request->file;

        $name = time() . $file[0]->getClientOriginalName(); // prepend the time (integer) to the original file name

        $file[0]->move('uploads', $name); // move it to the 'uploads' directory (public/uploads)

        // // create instance of Intervention Image
        $img = Image::make('uploads/'.$name)->resize(300,200);
        $img->save(public_path().'/uploads/'.$name);

    }
```

And this is my view for uploading gallery & header image:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputFile">Index image:</label>
<input type="file" name="headerImage" value="{{$object->headerImage}}">
<img src="{{asset('FrontAssets/img/smjestaj/')}}/{{$object->headerImage}}" style="width: 100px;">

<p class="help-block">Image that will be displayed on index page.</p>
```

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputFile">Image gallery</label>
<input type="file" name="img[]" multiple>

<p class="help-block">Choose x images for that will be displayed on gallery page.</p>
```

And it displays me this error:

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null

Note: I have "enctype="multipart/form-data" in my form.

[This is what I get when i do dd();](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DC3mT.png)

I hope I described my problem correctly, if I need to add anything else please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are trying to getClientOriginalName on array , try : $file[0] = $request->file[0] instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your html

```
<input type="file" name="headerImage" value="{{$object->headerImage}}">
```

and

```
<input type="file" name="img[]" multiple>
```

Try changing

From

```
foreach ($request['img'] as $img) {
            $gallery = new Gallery();
            $gallery->objects_id=$id;
            $gallery->img=$img;
            $gallery->save();


            $file[0] = $request->file;

            $name = time() . $file[0]->getClientOriginalName(); // prepend the time (integer) to the original file name

            $file[0]->move('uploads', $name); // move it to the 'uploads' directory (public/uploads)

            // // create instance of Intervention Image
            $img = Image::make('uploads/'.$name)->resize(300,200);
            $img->save(public_path().'/uploads/'.$name);

        }
```

To

```
if($request->file('img'))
 {
    foreach ($request->file('img') as $key => $file) {
       $gallery = new Gallery();
       $gallery->objects_id=$id;
       $gallery->img=$file;
       $gallery->save();

       $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
       $destination = base_path() . '/public/uploads';
       $file->move($destination, $name);
     }
 }
if($request->file('headerImage'))
{
    $name = time() . $request->file('headerImage')->getClientOriginalName();
    $destination = base_path() . '/public/uploads';
    $request->file('headerImage')->move($destination, $name);
}
```

Comment: I did as you told me, I got no errors but my files didn't move to "uploads" folder

Comment: @zlatangoralija I updated my answer please check now and also check value of $destination is it proper not?

Comment: I finally made it to work, it's not exactly as your code, but it helped me a lot and I saw where I made a mistake. Thank you!